# MYSQL sort by date with maximum date

Tags: mysql, wordpress, date

Well I am working with wordpress and I'm trying to sort some posts by the date custom field that contains a date. Well i can sort the results by date, but I only want to show results that have a date until today. I don't want to get results from a post that has a future date.

This is the code i'm using:

```
$querystr = "
            SELECT wposts.*
            FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
            WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
            AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'date'
            AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
            AND wposts.post_type = games'
            ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(wpostmeta.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y') DESC
            ";

        $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

Comment: can you post a row example from your database please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to where clause:

```
AND STR_TO_DATE(wpostmeta.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y') <= DATE(NOW())
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add it to your where clause:

```
SELECT wposts.*
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
  AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'date'
  AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
  AND wposts.post_type = 'games'
  AND STR_TO_DATE(wpostmeta.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y') < NOW()
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(wpostmeta.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y') ASC
```

Comment: Should be '<= DATE(NOW())' not '< NOW()'.   On 2nd thought, dates probably count as midnight when compared to timestamps (00:00:00 hours), so I think < NOW() will work perfectly.  Sorry.

Comment: I tested it out by doing `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE STR_TO_DATE('12/16/2011', '%m/%d/%Y') < NOW()` (and '12/17/2011'), and it worked as I expected.  As you said, casting with `DATE()` would only work if you have `<=`  Either one works, I think.  :)

Comment: Although, I just noticed that the OP forgot a quote in the `post_type` where line...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your row of data I would think something like this would do the trick:

```
$today = "12/16/2011";

$querystr = "SELECT wposts.*
            FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
            WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
            AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'date'
            AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
            AND wposts.post_type = 'games'
            STR_TO_DATE(wpostmeta.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y') <= $today;
            ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(wpostmeta.meta_value, '%m/%d/%Y') ASC";
```

Where you are generating today's date in PHP in the same format as %m/%d/%Y

Answer (score -2):

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE >= [start DATE] AND STR_TO_DATE <= [END DATE]
```

Comment: not what OP wanted and doesn't even work, STR_TO_DATE is a function, not an actual date

Comment: So you're statement should actually be some kind of pseudo code? But anyway, OP wanted all entries before today, not all entries in a certain range.